# serial interfacing of 89s52 with Hyperterminal... getting garbage values

Tags: serial-port, embedded, microcontroller, robotics, 8051

I need to transfer data serially from AT89s52 to Hyperterminal of PC.
For that I made a sample program to print "Hello" on the hyperterminal of my PC by programming the below given code inside 89s52 microcontroller and connecting it to my PC via serial port. Now when I am opening hyperterminal for the respective port, I should be seeing "Hello" printed on the screen multiple times, but what actually I am seeing is some garbage data getting printed.
This is the code I have used.

```
#include < AT89X52.H>

#include < STDLIB.H> 

#include < STDIO.H> 

unsigned int i; 

void main (void) 

{ 

TMOD = 0x20; 

SCON = 0x50; 

TH1 = 0xFD; 

TL1 = 0xFD; 

TR1 = 1; 

TI = 1; 

P1 = 0; 

while (1) 

{ 

puts("Hello\r"); 

P1 ^= 0x01; /* Toggle P1.0 each time we print */ 

for(i=0;i<25000;i++); 

} 

}
```

In the Hyper terminal I am not getting correct output i.e. Hello. Instead I am seeing some Garbage characters..
Can anybody help on this please..?

Comment: Have you matched the baud rate and number of stop bits at each end?

Comment: yes.. its 9600 and Stop bit=1,

Comment: Covered pretty well by [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70126/find-th1-in-at89s52-micro-controller-in-serial-communication), also the site where you want to ask questions like this.

Comment: Try to change your baud rates inside your Microcontroller and Hyperterminal by trial and error if you are not sure which rate is appropriate.

Comment: What's the crystal frequency?

Comment: @LPs:
Frequency is 11.0592

Answer (score 0):

Can you See P1 is toggling? I would rather send a single character first and observe what is sending by using an oscilloscope. You should see a digital signal corresponding to the ASCII value of the character being split-out from the TX pin of the micro. Also you can check the baud rate (exact value) by using the scope. If you are convinced that the correct value is sent at the right baud rate it is most likely that you got a bad connection or perhaps the baud rate should slightly be changed.